# React TS, First submit returns empty array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**I'm trying to make simple form using React,Typescript, have done some inputs and while adding them with onChange to one main state, first submit always returns empty. Why?**

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Form } from "../components/Form/Form";
import { Navbar } from "../components/Navbar";



export const MainPage = () => {

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="w-full flex">
      <Navbar />
      <Form formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

interface Props{
  formData: string[];
  setFormData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>;
}


export const Form: React.FC<Props> = ({setFormData, formData}) => {
  const [organization, setOrganization] = useState<string>("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState<string>("");
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState<string>("");
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState<string>("");
  const [languages, setLanguages] = useState<string>("");
  const [employmentType, setEmploymentType] = useState<string>("");
  const [profession, setProfession] = useState<string>("");
  const [proficiency, setProficiency] = useState<string>("");

  const submitData = (e: any) => {
    const data = {
      organization,
      title,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      languages,
      employmentType,
      profession,
      proficiency,
    };
    setFormData((prevData: any) => [...prevData, data]);
    console.log(formData)
  }


  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <div className="w-3/4 mx-auto mt-5">
        <h1 className="text-2xl">About you</h1>
        <div className="top flex mt-16 gap-8">
          <div>
            <h2 className="text-xl font-bold">Personal info</h2>
            <p className="text-sm font-extralight">
              Provide your personal info
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-5">
            <div>
              <input
                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                  setOrganization(e.target.value);
                }}
                className="w-full bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md placeholder:text-sm placeholder:text-black"
                placeholder="Organization"
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="flex gap-3">
              <select
                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
                  setTitle(e.target.value);
                }}
                className="bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md placeholder:text-sm placeholder:text-black"
              >
                <option value="Title">Title</option>
                <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
              </select>
              <input
                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                  setFirstName(e.target.value);
                }}
                className="bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md placeholder:text-sm placeholder:text-black"
                placeholder="First name"
              ></input>
              <input
                onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                  setLastName(e.target.value);
                }}
                className="bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md placeholder:text-sm placeholder:text-black"
                placeholder="Last name"
              ></input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr className="mt-16"></hr>

      <div className="bottom w-3/4 mx-auto mt-16">
        <div>
          <h2 className="text-xl font-bold">Professional info</h2>
          <p className="text-sm font-extralight">
            Provide your professional info
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-14">
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-8 items-center">
            <input
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                setLanguages(e.target.value);
              }}
              className="w-3/4 bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md placeholder:text-sm placeholder:text-black"
              placeholder="Language(s) separate with comma"
            ></input>
            <input
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                setEmploymentType(e.target.value);
              }}
              className="w-3/4 bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md placeholder:text-sm placeholder:text-black"
              placeholder="Type of employment"
            ></input>
            <input
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                setProfession(e.target.value);
              }}
              className="w-3/4 bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md placeholder:text-sm placeholder:text-black"
              placeholder="Profession"
            ></input>
            <input
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                setProficiency(e.target.value);
              }}
              className="w-3/4 bg-gray-200 p-2 rounded-md placeholder:text-sm placeholder:text-black"
              placeholder="Proficiency level"
            ></input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-3/4 flex justify-end mt-7">
        <button onClick={(e) => submitData(e)} className="bg-sky-800 p-2 text-white rounded-md">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Read other threads about similar issue but there was mentioned using async, i believe there would be another way to fix this. Thank you

Comment: seems like it is logging initial state of formData variable which is blank array make sure you set default value of form to formData

Answer (score 0):

Hi there setState in Reactjs is asynchronous so when you called submitData console.log(formData) gets triggered even before the setState completed its task and with asynchronous code, javascript does not have to wait for setState to finish up it just keeps running other tasks.

```
setFormData((prevData: anyType) => {
    const newData = [...prevData, data];
    console.log(newData);
    return newData;
});
```